# how to add non-ascii characters in Xpath, in Scrappy

Tags: python, xpath, unicode, ascii

I have the following Xpath:

```
bathroom = response.xpath(“.//div[1][contains(., 'Baños’)]/text()").extract_first()
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

I've tried the solutions given in these other similar questions:

[Filtering out certain bytes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733233/filtering-out-certain-bytes-in-python)

[Scrapy xpath utf-8 literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892473/scrapy-xpath-utf-8-literals)

but none has resolved my problem!

**Note:** with the solution of the first link, I obviously replaced the 'input_string' by let's say `word = "baños"`, and I got an error like **"*the function has one argument, 2 given...*"**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the literal `Baños`, your code snippet contains invalid literal string delimiter (both single and double quotes) which will cause a different error :

```
bathroom = response.xpath(“.//div[1][contains(., 'Baños’)]/text()").extract_first()
                          ^                            ^
```

Converting the entire XPath expression to unicode, as suggested in the 2nd link, and fixing the two quotes pointed above should fix the initial errors. Below as a quick test using `lxml` (which scrapy uses under the hood) :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring('<root/>')
>>> root.xpath(u".//div[1][contains(., 'Baños')]/text()")
[]
```

Comment: I've tried what you say, but I still get this error: `ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in .//div[1][contains(., 'Ba\xf1os')]/text()`

Comment: Tested even in the actual scrapy shell with the following expression and no error (see what's different in your actual code, or try to copy paste from this code and run in your machine) : `r = response.xpath(u".//div[1][contains(., 'Baños')]/text()").extract_first()`

Comment: ok, I show you how is my full '*Xpath*' (I cut it a bit, cos was too long, but it's basically the same): `bathroom = response.xpath(u".//*[@id='details']/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1][contains(., 'Baños')]/div[contains(., 'Baños')]/div[contains(., 'Baños')])]/div/span[3]/span/text()").extract_first()`

Comment: This part contains too many `]`, hence Invalid XPath error : `/div[contains(., 'Baños')]/div[contains(., 'Baños')])]`

Comment: yeah, you're right...I should definitely go to bed after this error of mine...xD thanks a lot for your help! :):)